# Can we renew session in Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am storing 5-6 variable values in my session. Any suggestions on how can I renew my session struct when its about to expire? I am using Coldfusion 8.
Thanks!!

Comment: Unless you are under intense load you can probably just extend the session timeout and see no performance hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use AJAX to ping the server to keep the session alive

Or just simply extend the session timeout timeSpand.

Comment: Do I have to do something in ajax call, or could it return just a blank result in order to renew the session?

Comment: Your AJAX call should hit a CFM page or CFC method.  This can do nothing, and return (for example) the empty string, but it needs to be part of the same application in order to be used as a keep-alive.

Answer (score 2):

Any call to a CFM page from that session would cause the session to be extended. What I have seen done is a JS timer will be running and end shortly before the session expires. When the timer runs up it triggers a popup that loads a non CFM page(basic HTML) and that page states a message about the session ending soon and asking the user if they'd like to continue it.

Comment: This is a good way to handle it.  You probably still want inactive sessions to time out eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea of what Ajax to automatically ping the server could look like (as suggested in [Henry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5782450/3680712).)

```
//This function will keep the session alive as long as the page is still open.
//Whenever the page nears expiration, it automatically extends it. 
function autoExtendSession(days,hours,mins,secs){
    var milliseconds = (days*86400000)+(hours*3600000)+(mins*60000)+(secs*1000);
    setTimeout(
    function(){
        $.post("server/heartbeat.cfm");
        console.log("Heartbeat sent to the server.");

        //Start another timer.
        autoExtendSession(days,hours,mins,secs)

    //Once we are 98% of the way to the timeout, the heartbeat is sent.
    //This way the timeout should never actually be reached.
    }, milliseconds-(milliseconds*0.02));
};
```

The `hearbeat.cfm` page doesn't actually have to contain anything, the server will renew the session when the $.post hits it, whether or not it has content.

Answer (score 0):

*Exact* way of doing what you are asking for is to push session data into the database when `onSessionEnd` fired and restore it on next `onSessionStart`. To find out the data entries to read you can put cookie into the user's browser with unique identifier (for example, salted+encrypted id of that entry), kind of "Remember me" stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting your session timeout to something small, say 5min.

Then when someone authenticates, extend the session timeout to something larger, 30min.

And if they signout, drop it back down.

eg. configure your cf admin with a 5 minute session timeout.

On sign in:

```
<cfscript>
// extend session timeout to 1800 seconds (30min)
session.SetMaxInactiveInterval( javaCast( 'long', 1800 ) );
</cfscript>
```

On sign out:

```
<cfscript>
// shrink session timeout to 300 seconds (5min)
session.SetMaxInactiveInterval( javaCast( 'long', 300 ) );
</cfscript>
```

The session hangs around for another 5 minutes and then is cleaned up.
Unless you continue using the site, in which case each page request would give you a further 5min.