# What actions cause a Coldfusion session to be extended?

Tags: session, coldfusion, session-timeout

When you set up a ColdFusion session inside of a `application.cfm` or `application.cfc` file you can define a `sessionTimeout` like:

```
<cfapplication name = "appname" 
sessionTimeout = #CreateTimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0)# <!--- 30min timeout --->
sessionManagement = "yes">
```

I think that a ColdFusion session is 'extended' or 'renewed' every time:

1. The user navigates to a new ColdFusion Template (a .cfm file)
2. The user refreshes a Coldfusion Template (a .cfm file)
3. The user accesses a ColdFusion Component (a .cfc file) in any way, including via ajax calls that run a `cffunction` in the .cfc file.

In other words, if a user performs any of the actions above (assuming the `sessionTimeout` is 30 minutes like in the above example) the session will expire 30 minutes from when the action was performed--essentially 'extending' the life of the session to the value of `sessionTimeout` each time the user performs one of those actions.

Does this understanding sound correct? Are there any actions that 'extend' a ColdFusion session that I'm missing? Do the ones I listed actually behave how I think they behave and 'extend' the session?

Comment: To have a better understanding, think in terms client/server and maintaining state in a stateless environment like http requests. If the client is a browser, delete the cookies and you lost your session at that moment. The server doesn't know who you are anymore.

Comment: Yes, that is how ColdFusion knows which user to associate it's server-side session variables with. By default, after a server-specified amount of time ColdFusion considers the session associated with a cookie to be too old/expired. There are a few actions that reset the session's `sessionTimeout` back to the original `sessionTimeout` (aka 'renew' it), such as refreshing a cfm page (which is processed by the server before being delivered as HTML/JS) visiting a new cfm page (also hits the server) and accessing a cfc (also hits the server.) I'm just wondering if I missed any.

Comment: Looks like (by default) in ColdFusion anything that hits the server gives the session a little more time to "live".

Comment: You seem to understand everything.  Is this a matter of simple curiosity or is there something you are looking to accomplish?

Comment: Purely academic. I'm working on a little JS library to make it easier for me to warn users about the expiration of their ColdFusion sessions, redirect them to a login page when their session expires, and also allow them to extend/renew their session if they want to. I just wanted to make sure I was taking into account all the possible ways to renew a CF session so I was using the best one for my 'hearbeats' to the server. This is the library https://github.com/Ectropy/clockworkHeart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar was asked here: [Can we renew session in Coldfusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782420/can-we-renew-session-in-coldfusion)

What Alex says is true.  There is a way of maintaining a session without cookies if you look at the docs. Check out the section [Using client and session variables without cookies](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fef.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7cbf).

The only other way I can think of extending a session without user intervention would be if you can find the session through SessionTracker.  Here's a nice post about it:  [Advanced ColdFusion Session Management](http://www.neiland.net/blog/article/advanced-coldfusion-session-management/).

In fact, in the comments, it says that if you access the sessions through the built-in java methods, you might extend them:

> You might want to note that as soon as you access any sessions through
>   those methods, you'll update the "lastAccessed" timestamp.

Comment: Interesting! So you could extend how long a session lives by accessing it via session tracker. That is certainly a technique I never would have thought of! I guess that makes 4 known ways of 'renewing' a session--refreshing a cfm, opening a new cfm, accessing a cfc via ajax, and directly accessing a session via sessionTracker.